# Is $\iint\limits_{D}\frac{1}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{5}+5}dx\,dy$ convergent in $D=[0,+\infty)\times[0,+\infty)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

Can you tell me whether my approach is correct.

We first switch to polar coordinates and we get the following integral:

$\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{r}{r^{10}+5}d\phi dr=\int\limits _{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\phi\int\limits _{0}^{\infty}\frac{r}{r^{10}+5}dr=\frac{\pi}{2}\int\limits _{0}^{\infty}\frac{r}{r^{10}+5}dr$

From now on we solve it as it were an improper integral of single variable. We know that $\int\limits _{1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{r^{\alpha}}$ is convergent $\iff\alpha\ge2$.

We use the following criteria. Let $F(x)\ge 0,\,G(x)\ge 0$ be such that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}=\lambda,\lambda\in\mathbb{{R}}\cup\{+\infty\}$. If $\lambda$ is real and if $\int\limits_{a}^{+\infty}G(x)dx$ is convergent $\implies \int\limits _{a}^{+\infty}F(x)dx$ is also convergent.

We take $G(r)=\frac{1}{r^{9}}$ and compute $\lim\limits_{r\to\infty}\frac{F(r)}{G(r)}=\frac{r^{10}}{r^{10}+5}=1$, hence the integral is convergent.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me

Comment: Your condition $\alpha \ge 2$ should be $\alpha > 1$.

Comment: Another possibility is just to substitute $u = r^2$, which gives $\frac{1}{2(u^5+5)} \leq \frac{1}{u^5}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler to say that $0 < \frac{r}{r^{10}+5} < \frac1{r^9}$ in $[1,\infty)$, and $\int\limits_1^{\infty}\frac1{r^9}dr$ converges, so $\int\limits_1^{\infty}\frac{r}{r^{10}+5}dr$ converges.

(Also, $0 \le \frac{r}{r^{10}+5} < \frac15$ in $[0,1]$, so $\int\limits_0^1\frac{r}{r^{10}+5}dr$ converges.)